# What is the proper way to construct a sentence with two nouns?

Tags: nouns

Is *knight templar* the correct form to describe a man with the grade of knight who is part of the Templar order, or *templar knight* is more correct?

Sentence example:

> He was a knight templar.

or

> He was a templar knight.

I do not know if the order is important, but in this example: the man was first a Templar and later received the rank of knight.

Comment: Since a dictionary answers that questions it's considered off topic.

Comment: @Helmar To me knight templar is the correct way but i have found that the use of the term templar knight is common in many books and now i'm very confused.

Comment: I mentioned a dictionary

Comment: @Helmar wiktionary.org says the correct use is knight templar, but what about the templar knight is it incorrect.

Comment: @Helmar or all these people also need a dictionary ?